# Is my MP4 file size too big?

Tags: editing, mp4, davinci-resolve, filming, rendering

I am working on a film, which I'm editing, and I rendered the one-hour long video to MP4, and the file size is 64,8 GB, and I think it's absurd, when google says the typical file size for MP4 is 700 MB per hour. What did I do wrong? The video uses the H265 codec, and its 4096x1716 pixels, 24 fps, the bitrate is 148267. For audio, the bitrate is 195kbps, stereo, and the sample rate is 48.000 kHz.

Answer (score 1):

Resolve’s default bitrates err on the side of caution.  For most use cases, it’s ok to reduce the default bitrate significantly, but an exact amount is subjective, and depends largely on the source footage and your intended delivery target.  If you care more about file size than artifacts, and especially if there’s not much high-frequency detail and not much camera movement, you can get away with a tenfold reduction for h.264.  H.265 will require some experimentation, especially if you’re trying to deliver HDR.  Audio has a negligible effect on file size *vs* video bitrate.